# how to fetch sum every row mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Hy I have 2  table
1.application
`id | name    | status`
`====================`
`1 | morvick  | complete`
`2 | siti     | prosess`
`3 | boby     | complete`
`

2.application_test
`id | application_id  | test_id | result`
`======================================`
`1 | 1  |              1 |       70`
`2 | 1  |              2 |       80`
`3 | 1  |              3 |       90`
`4 | 2  |              1 |       60`
`5 | 2  |              2 |       80`
`6 | 2  |              3 |       70`
`7 | 3  |              1 |       90`
`8 | 3  |              2 |       70`
`9 | 3  |              3 |       60`
`10| 3  |              4 |       80`
my Question is :
==================
1. how I can to get sum(result) on each test_id where status complete
2. how I can to get sum(result) on each test_id where status prosess

for example to be like this :
`test_id | SUM(result = complete) | SUM(result = proses) |`
`1       | 90         | 50`
`2       | 80         | 40`
`3       | 90         | 60`
`4       | 80         | 70`

Comment: What have you already tried? Are you looking for writing SQL query, PHP code or Laravel models together with query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query-

```
SELECT test_id, 
SUM(IF(app.status='complete',apt.result,0)) AS complete_sum, 
SUM(IF(app.status='process',apt.result,0)) AS process_sum  
FROM application_test AS apt 
JOIN application AS app ON app.id=apt.application_id 
GROUP BY apt.test_id
```

Comment: pls explain how you achieve this. and whats the logic behind this query.

Comment: hy Zafar Malik, what the meaning **apt.result,0** because if i'm change to be app.status,0 it's deffrent result thanks

Comment: in one column you need only result where status is complete, so query made result 0 for other status in that column...plz let me know if you are not getting desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You can try two query to get sum of result

```
SELECT test_id , SUM (result) 
FROM application a 
JOIN application_test t 
ON t.test_id = a.id 
WHERE a.status = 'complete'
GROUP BY test_id 

SELECT test_id , SUM (result) 
FROM application a 
JOIN application_test t 
ON t.test_id = a.id 
WHERE a.status = 'prosess'
GROUP BY test_id
```

if you want in one query

```
SELECT test_id, 
SUM(IF(a.status='complete',result,0)) Completed , 
SUM(IF(a.status='process',result,0)) Process  
FROM  application  a 
JOIN application_test t
ON a.id=t.application_id 
GROUP BY t.test_id
```

Comment: Hy, Vipin Jain, I think this not work because **field result in table application_tes not in table applicant**

Comment: sorry by mistake i write quickly. it will t.result.